# Find command in linux bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

the find command is:

```
find ./ \( -path dir_a -o -path dir_b \) -prune
```

I want to convert to:

```
./find.sh dir_a dir_b
```

so my code (is doesn't work):

```
function myfind() {
   num=1
   tmp=""
   for i in $@
   do
       tmp="$tmp -path './$i' "
       if [ $((num++)) -ne $# ]
       then
           tmp="${tmp} -o"
       fi
   done
   echo $tmp # this is ok!!
   find ./ \( $tmp \) -prune # is doesn't work, why???
}
```

Comment: Don't use single variable `tmp` Use [array](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) instead. Check last code snippetunder `quoting` in [this link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting)

Comment: Your use of `$@` unquoted is clearly wrong. It needs to be in double quotes to have its special meaning, distinct from `$*` (quoted or unquoted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting cannot be solved in the general case with "classic `sh`" because you need your script to work correctly with directories named `*` or `'"[ ]"'`, and plain old flat strings simply don't allow that to be properly quoted (easily, or even with a fair amount of complexity).  Fortunately, as suggested in a comment, Bash arrays allow you to do this with all the necessary level of control.  Just make sure to always use quotes around anything which could contain a file name.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir_args=()
oh=
for i; do
    dir_args+=($oh '-path' "$i")
    oh='-o'
done
find . \( "${dir_args[@]}" \) -prune
```

Comment: It's not that difficult to do it in POSIX shell: something like `[ "$#" -eq 0 ] && exit; i=$#; set -- "$@" -false; while [ "$i" -gt 0 ]; do s=$1; shift; set -- "$@" -o -path "$s"; i=$((i-1)); done; find . \( "$@" \) -prune`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Hey, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: No… there's nothing conceptually different from your answer (which is the correct answer and that I upvoted). You may include it in yours, or leave it as a comment for future reference.